# Hide shipping based on category in Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm trying to hide all shipping options for one specific category but I can't figure out how to get it to work.  Here is what I have so far based on another answer:

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_based_on_tag' ,    4, 5 );

function check_cart_for_share() {

// specify the category id's you want to hide local_pickup
 $category_ID = array('332');
global $woocommerce;
$cart = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents;

$found = false;

// loop through the array looking for the categories. Switch to true if the category is found.
  foreach ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) {
        $terms = get_the_terms( $values['product_id'], 'product_cat' );
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            if( in_array( $term->term_id, $category_ID ) ) {

        $found = true;
        break;
    }
  }
}

return $found;

}

function hide_shipping_based_on_tag( $available_methods ) {

// use the function above to check the cart for the categories.
if ( check_cart_for_share() ) {

    // remove the method you want
    unset( $available_methods['ups'] ); // Replace "local_pickup" with the shipping option that you want to remove.
}

// return the available methods without the one you unset.
return $available_methods;

}
```

I'm trying to hide all shipping options for that category or if that's not possible just show a Free Pickup option.  I can't seem to be able to stop the other shipping options from showing.

If this is helpful this is the website - https://waterfrontembroidery.com

It's for the store Brookside Lumber that needs to go through without any shipping options showing is that possible?

In my code I included I'm not sure what to put in the fields.  At the top where it has 'hide_shipping_based_on_tag' The 4 & 5 are the id's for the UPS and Local Pickup I want to hide.

The category I want this on is "Brookside Lumber".

I appreciate any help someone can give me!